# Modal opens in all browsers other than Safari

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a page where I have a floating, draggable modal, allowing me access to the background while the modal is open. The following works in every browser other than Safari. Any ideas? Fiddle below fails in Safari.

CSS

```
#myModal {
  position: relative;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="openModal">Show Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Draggable Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal Body
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('#openModal').click(function() {
  if (!($('.modal.in').length)) {
    $('.modal-dialog').css({
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    });
  }
  $('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: false,
    show: true
  });

  $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7vrhLk40/

Comment: your css for #myModal adding position relative is causing it to render oddly, remove that and the fiddle works. https://jsfiddle.net/7vrhLk40/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the position relative from your #myModal element.

```js
$('#openModal').click(function() {
  if (!($('.modal.in').length)) {
    $('.modal-dialog').css({
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    });
  }
  $('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: false,
    show: true
  });

  $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="openModal">Show Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Draggable Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal Body
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That has fixed it. Thank you very much.